# Authentication with Back-end Spring Security Java EE Server and Front-end iOS Objective-C client

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, spring-security

I want to authenticate a user connected on his iOS app on a Java EE server Back-end.
Here, you can find my spring security configuration back-end :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/home.mediator" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginInvalid.security" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout*" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <form-login login-page="/home.mediator" 
            default-target-url="/loginValid.security"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginInvalid.security" />

        <logout invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess.security" 
            logout-url="/logout.do"/>

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

This work perfectly on the browser on the back-office web application.
But the problem is when i access my Back-end Java EE server with my iOS objective-C client for authentication process like this :

```
    NSString *login = self.loginTextField.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordTextField.text;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/myJeeServer/j_spring_security_check"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"j_username=%@&j_password=%@",login,password];
    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *err;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Request : %@",request);
    NSLog(@"Response : %d",urlResponse.statusCode);
    NSLog(@"Error : %d",err.code);
```

I've got every time an HTTP Response status code to 200, i can't check if the authentication was an success or a failure according to the iOS client side. Maybe this way is the wrong way to implement an authentication with Spring security Back-end and Objective-C client Front-end but i did not found any others ways on the web. Can someone help me with this security use case please ? What is the best way to authenticate user with objective-C and Spring security ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Assuming your JEE server runs on your computer and your iOS code in iPhone/iPad emulator, are you sure `localhost` should work?

Comment: Yes it works, because when i shutdown my server on localhost i got an error.code. In addition, i got confirmation with logs on my JEE server :
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:317 - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbd56702:

Comment: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe21a0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 4D3C8B8C3C12B461DEEA82143D1DF8B2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER

Comment: Here my iOS client logs if we changed localhost by 127.0.0.1, i got the same result :
2013-06-16 22:17:43.928 iosClient[11273:11303] Request : <NSMutableURLRequest http://127.0.0.1:8080/myJeeServer/j_spring_security_check>
2013-06-16 22:17:43.929 iosClient[11273:11303] Response : 200
2013-06-16 22:17:43.930 iosClient[11273:11303] Error : 0

Thanks.

Comment: Ok... now I understand. `NSMutableURLRequest` probably transparently follows redirects, so you don't know whether you were redirected to auth-success or auth-failure URL. Both return response code 200.

Comment: Yes, response status code always return 200 except if the HTTP request failed (Bad url, network off, ...) then status code is equals to 0 and error code to -1004.
I try to find a criteria to evaluate if auth-success or auth-failure in my front-end objective-C client but i can't get access to property values like Enabled, AccountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, Granted Authorities, etc ... in the HTTP response.

Comment: If you back-end is really a pure back-end application, you probably don't want to use form-based authentication. If you want to keep things simple, go for BASIC authentication over HTTPS. You can then have `/authentication` resource, which will either return authorities on successful authentication or authentication error in case of any problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a pure back-end application, it's also a back-office web application, for administration tasks (Manage users, reporting,...). So i need the form-based authentication for my back-office authentication HTML view.

Comment: If you have web services at `/api/**` you can secure that with BASIC and the rest with FORM. If you want access to the same resources, you can configure custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, which will act based on some request header. If you send some custom header (e.g. `X-Client: Mobile`), you can return 403 status code instead of doing redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,

I forgot to put the solution of this old topic so below one possible solution for developers facing same situation :

- sample of login on iOS Client over HTTP with spring security authentication behind :

-(IBAction)connect:(UIButton *)sender {

```
        // Get login and password values
        NSString *login = self.loginTextField.text;
        NSString *password = self.passwordTextField.text;

        // Check if they are not empty before HTTP call
        if([login isEqualToString:@""] || [password isEqualToString:@""]) {
            self.loginResponse.text = @"Please select a login and a password before connect.";
            return;
        } else {
            self.userLogin = login;
            self.userPassword = password;
        }

        // Prepare request for login
        NSString *restRequest =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/rest/%@",IP_SERVER,REST_LOGIN_OPERATION];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:restRequest]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"j_username=%@&j_password=%@&submit=Login",self.userLogin,self.userPassword];
        [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // start the animation if it's not already going
        [self.spinner startAnimating];

        dispatch_queue_t loginQ = dispatch_queue_create("endoServerLoginQueue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(loginQ, ^(){
            // call Web Service REST on EndoServer for login
            NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
            NSError *err;
            NSData *urlData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&err];

            // Log async call request
            NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Request for customer login : %@",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), request);

            // When we have the results, use main queue to display them
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                // Parse data
                NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                // Log async call response
                NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Response status code for doctor login : %d",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), urlResponse.statusCode);
                NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Response body for doctor login : (doctor id = %@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), str);
                NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Error code for doctor login : %d",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), err.code);

                if(urlResponse.statusCode == 200) {

                    [self.logoutButton setEnabled:YES];

                    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Connection Success for Customer login (%@) and Password (%@).",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.userLogin,self.userPassword);


                    // Save login and password in user preferences
                    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [userPreferences setObject:self.userLogin forKey:USER_LOGIN_KEY];
                    [userPreferences setObject:self.userPassword forKey:USER_PASSWORD_KEY];
                    [userPreferences setInteger:[str integerValue] forKey:USER_ID_KEY];
                    [userPreferences synchronize];

                    // Go to Home screen view
                    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@ ! ",self.userLogin];
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToHomePage" sender:self];
                }

                if(err.code == -1004) {
                    str = @"Server is shutdown, please try later or contact administrator.";
                    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Error message : %@",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), str);
                }

                self.loginResponse.text = str; // makes UIKit calls, so must be main thread
                [self.spinner stopAnimating]; // stop the animation
            });
        });
```

}

- Sample of spring security configuration with custom authentication handler:

  .....

  ```
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com....." />

  ....

  <!-- 
      Add Rest API access for mobile devices
   -->
  <http pattern="/rest/**" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
      <intercept-url pattern="/rest/login" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/rest/customer/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/rest/logout" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <form-login login-processing-url="/rest/login"
                  authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                  authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
      <logout success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" logout-url="/rest/logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
  </http>


  ....
  ```

and sample of handler implementation :

```
@Component(value = "customAuthenticationSuccessHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (hasRoleCustomer(authentication)) {
            String username = authentication.getName();
            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().print(user.getId());
            LOGGER.info("Authentication Success for customer : "+user.getUsername()+", with id : "+user.getId());
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.getWriter().print("Access Denied, please contact the administrator.");
            LOGGER.info("Access denied for customer : "+authentication.getName());
        }
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
```

Others required handler should be implemented in the same way according to your business requirements.