# Authentication of spring security with iOS app

Tags: ios, authentication, spring-security, http-post, nsurlconnection

I would like to implement spring security authentication for iOS app. 
Any help is appreciated. I looked in post like the below one but its not working.

[Authentication with Back-end Spring Security Java EE Server and Front-end iOS Objective-C client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137034/authentication-with-back-end-spring-security-java-ee-server-and-front-end-ios-ob)

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the authentication for the backend like a rest API http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/#ch_3_4

If you are using NSURLConnection in iOS you can use the error and other delegate methods to catch authentication errors.